# Schedule php function once a day

Tags: php, schedule

I have a question..
Is there any way to run a php function once a day. For example. I have a function which find every Sunday of next year and apply some offers (such as discount to all products etc.) This function run every time that users refresh the page. I want to run this function once a day in order to check if that day is Sunday. If Sunday then it will execute, otherwise It will not execute. Any ideas?

Comment: Google *"cron"* - and just schedule for Sunday...

Comment: I think what you need is a cron job

Comment: Of cource I heard it and I find for the solution there :) Anyway! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using **cron**.
If you want another way without using cron check this stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865381/how-can-i-run-php-script-in-certain-interval-e-g-once-a-day).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows you can use the [task scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task).

Answer (score 0):

**If you're using LINUX**

Use Cron Jobs

```
# run the script at 4:30am every day
30 4 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/me/myscript.php
```

**If you're using WINDOWS**

Use [sheduled task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ie/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)

If you're using XAMP

```
C:\xampp\php\php.exe -f c:/xampp/htdocs/myscript.php
```